# Problem about the generalized pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

**This problem from Discrete Mathematics and its application's for Rosen**

> What is the least number of area codes needed to guarantee that the 25
> million phones in a state can be assigned distinct 10-digit telephone
> numbers? (Assume that telephone numbers are of the form NXX-NXX-XXXX,
> where the first three digits form the area code, N represents a digit
> from 2 to 9 inclusive, and X represents any digit.)

**The answer I found in the book is :**

> There are eight million different phone numbers of the form NXX-XXXX
> (as shown in Example 8 of Section 6.1). Hence, by the generalized
> pigeonhole principle, among 25 million telephones, at least
> $\lceil25,000,000/8,000,000\rceil = 4$ of them must have identical phone numbers.
> Hence, at least four area codes are required to ensure that all
> 10-digit numbers are different

***Can anyone please explain this answer as I tried a lot to understand it but I can't.***

Comment: Do you understand that there are eight million distinct phone numbers?

Comment: yes of the form NXX-XXXX

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are at most $8,000,000$ distinct numbers in an area code, if we had $3$ areas codes, we could only accommodate $3\cdot8,000,00=24,000,000$ phone numbers.  If we have $4$ area codes, we can accommodate $4\cdot8,000,00=32,000,000$ numbers, so we need $4$.

The short way to do this is to notice that $$\frac{25,000,000}{8,000,000}=\frac{25}8=3.125$$ so that $3$ area codes won't be enough, but $4$ will be.  The most compact way of writing it is that we need $$\left\lceil\frac{25,000,000}{8,000,000}\right\rceil$$ area codes.

Comment: why 4 area codes give us 4 * 8,000,000  ? 
 I think it will give us  10^4 * 8,000,000 as 4 area codes is a number with 4 digits as i think

Comment: @HUMAN An area code is a sequence of $3$ digits like $123$  For any fixed area code, there are $8,000,000$ possible numbers.

Comment: @saulspatz. Amazing explanation. Thank you. In case of 8 million numbers, this is a permutation, but this is not arrangement of numbers, so how do we know if we should use arrangement or not please?

Comment: @Avra I don't understand.  We are told that we have $8,000,000$ numbers for each area code.  This is not a permutation.  (The problem says that the numbers are of the form NXX-XXXX, so I suppose that there are $8$ choices for N and $10$ choices for each of the X's.)

Answer (score 2):

I honestly think the answer is a bit unclear as well, but here is my similar explanation. There are $8$ million possible numbers of the form NXX - XXXX since:
$$
8 \times 10^6 = 8,000,000.
$$
Imagine you divide the $25$ million phones into groups of $8$ million phones. Evidently you get $4$ groups, the last group (only $1$ million) of course not being all the way full (hence the ceiling function in the answer). Each of the first $3$ groups use **all** of the numbers exactly once, and then there is guaranteed repetition again when assigning the fourth group of $1$ million people phone numbers. However, no number is repeated *more than $4$ times*. Thus, by having $4$ distinct area codes NXX, we can avoid any repetition.

Comment: It’s not unclear: it just requires the reader to recognize that taking the ceiling of a positive number has the effect of rounding it up, so that any leftover ‘fractional’ group — in this case the extra million — is correctly counted as needing an area code.

Answer (score -1):

There are 8000000 telephone numbers of the form NXX-XXXX .( For first element i.e N we have 8 choices and for remaining 6 elements we have 10 choices for each so by product rule we have 8000000 choices).Then by generalized pigeon hole principle there must be at least [25000000/8000000]=4 of 25 millions telephones which have identical phone numbers. So at least 4 area codes are required to guarantee that all 10 digit numbers are different.